# Fix viewport width in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, width, scrollbar, viewport

I have this code:

```css
body
{
  margin: 0;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.cont
{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont"></div>
<br>
```

Chrome (and other browsers with the same engine) ignore the width of vertical scrollbar.

How I can fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the vw/vh unit takes into account the size of the entire viewport when sizing and does not take into account the width of the scroll bar.  A simple fix is to limit the max-width of the .cont element to not exceed the width of the document.

```
    .cont
    {
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
      background-color: #000;
      max-width: 100%; /*limit width*/
    }
```